# Compute the following integral along $y=1/2x^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, contour-integration

I think that there's a mistake. (Excersice taken from W. Fulks Advanced Calculus: An introduction to analysis)

Compute $\int_C 4xy^2dx-3x^4dy$ from $(1,1)$ to $(2,2)$ along $y=(1/2)x^2$. I think that this is wrong cuz $(1,1)$ doesn't belong to the path, as $x=1$ then $y=1/2$, is right my observation or there are a solution for this case? Any help would be useful.

Comment: You are right. It's probably a typo and it probably means $\left(1, \frac{1}{2}\right)$.